# MySQL Table Primary Index - Auto Number vs Two Column

Tags: mysql, database

First time asking on StackOverflow. I am creating a MySQL database where I have two tables

- a company table (company_id, company_name, etc.) which will have company_id as the primary key (up to 12 characters)*
- and the other table being its corporate representatives (maximum of five) with fields (company_id, person_last_name, etc.).  The representatives table does not have a natural primary key.

I will do queries that JOIN on the company_id field.  Everything works but I want to use proper conventions and maximize access speed.

**Question:** Is it better to add an Auto-Increment Integer Primary key to the representatives table even though it will never be used (by me) or add a person_count column and make a two column primary index (company_id, person_count)?

SQL Example:

```
SELECT company.company_id, company.company_name, representatives.person_last_name
FROM company INNER JOIN representatives 
  ON company.company_id = representatives.company_id;
```

representatives table option 1:
company_id (non-unique index), person_last_name, auto_id(auto-increment integer pri)

```
N123456789012, JONES, 1
N123456789012, SMITH, 2
N123456789012, JONES, 3
N123456789012, WHITE, 4
N123456789012, BLACK, 5
P1234, WILLIAMS, 6
P1234, WILLIAMS, 7
```

representatives table option 2:

```
[company_id, person_count](pri index), person_last_name

N123456789012, 1, JONES
N123456789012, 2, SMITH
N123456789012, 3, JONES
N123456789012, 4, WHITE
N123456789012, 5, BLACK
P1234, 1, WILLIAMS
P1234, 2, WILLIAMS
```

**I did not create the original data and do not have control over the company_id being a text field.**

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you have a good reason to do something different, I would suggest having an auto-increment single column PK. It's jut handy being able to refer to each unique row through a simple int. You might not have a use for it now but you will probably have one in the future. Even if you have to perform some manual maintenance on the table (manually delete or update some rows) the simple PK will come in handy.

However, if you want the database to enforce the 5 person per company limit, I would also use the person_count column, add a constraint to it so that it can only be between 1 and 5 and add a unique index to (company_id, person_count). That way, you get the best of both worlds.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  I will add both fields.  As a follow-up, acfrancis, would it be redundant to still have the company_id field indexed (non-unique) and add another unique index for (company_id, person_count)?  It is my understanding that I can still make a JOIN on just company_id even if it is a two field index.  Would you advise to have both indexes?

Comment: I think it is redundant. As long as you put the company_id as the first column, the unique index will be a good candidate for searches (like a join) on just the company_id (without the person_count).

Comment: OK @acfrancis, will try it that way.  The original data is imported from a csv.  It will be easier to add the person_count field at the end of the field list (along with the date stamp, etc.), but the company_id is the first field.  I am designing the tables first (which is against my nature) so can play before committing to production code.  I understand for readability (other programmers), the person_count field would be better as the second position so I may take the time to pre-map the csv import.

Comment: The position of the columns in the table is not important. I like to create new tables with a sensible order to make ad hoc ``select *`` queries more readable but over time you will add more columns to the end and that's OK. I was referring specifically to the unique index. That's where the column order matters.